# Ruby: Rescuing the same error type twice

Tags: ruby, exception

Is it possible to rescue the same error type more than once in ruby? I am needing to while using the Koala facebook API library like so:

```
begin
  # Try with user provided app token
  fb = Koala::Facebook::API.new(user_access_token)
  fb.put_connections(user_id, {}) # TODO
rescue AuthenticationError
  # User access token has expired or is fake
  fb = Koala::Facebook::API.new(APP_FB_TOKEN)
  fb.put_connections(user_id, {}) # TODO
rescue AuthenticationError
  # User hasn't authed the app on facebook
  puts "Could not authenticate"
  next
rescue => e
  puts "Error when posting to facebook"
  puts e.message
  next
end
```

If there is no way to rescue the same error twice, is there a better way of reasoning about this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should probably refactor this into two separate methods - a "safe" `authenticate` method that handles exceptions, and an "unsafe" `authenticate!` method that raises exceptions. `authenticate` should be defined in terms of `authenticate!`

Here's an example of how you could do it, with retry implementation thrown in for good measure.

EDIT: Refactored to make retries independent of the `authenticate` method.

```
def authenticate!
  fb = Koala::Facebook::API.new(user_access_token)
  fb.put_connections(user_id.to_s, )
end

def authenticate
  authenticate!
rescue => e
  warn "Error when posting to facebook: #{e.message}"
end

# @param [Integer] num_retries number of times to try code
def with_retries(num_retries=2)
  yield
rescue AuthenticationError
  # User hasn't authed the app on facebook
  puts "Could not authenticate"
  # Retry up to twice
  (num_retries-=1) < 1 ? raise : retry
end

# Authenticate safely, retrying up to 2 times
with_retries(2) { authenticate }

# Authenticate unsafely, retrying up to 3 times
with_retries(2) { authenticate! }
```

Comment: The only addition I would say on this, is to probably finally raise the AuhenticateError after the 2nd retry is completed.  If you do finally need to raise it.  It would allow this to be handled, rather than just displaying it to the screen, by other code that is calling it.  This way the error is not finally lost.

Comment: It might make even more sense to refactor the retry code into a separate method, so you could retry safely or unsafely.

Comment: I refactored so you can retry safely or unsafely.

Comment: Shouldn't `authenticate` call a private method called `with_retries` and pass in the block you want it to?  I see what you are doing there, but it should be internal implementation.

Comment: It could, but this way gives you more flexibility to choose whether or not to retry.

Comment: I like the idea, just not so much the implementation of having a separate method, rather than an option to by default not retry, or supply a number for the number of retries.  This way there is not another method to have to know, just an option.  That would still give you the choice, but would reduce the cognitive of having to know two separate methods.

Comment: Sure, there are tradeoffs either way. This isn't meant to be a perfect solution, it's just showing an example of how you could refactor this into separate methods. The retry functionality is just a bonus and isn't directly relevant to the original question. For what it's worth, this design is inspired by the [retryable gem](https://github.com/nfedyashev/retryable).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the gem.  I have written a few 'retry' procedures for doing user interaction (things where you expect problems, but want to give a chance to correct), so it is always good to see how others do it.

Answer (score 4):

I think the only way is to have a new `try-rescue` clause inside the `rescue` clause:

```
begin
  # Try with user provided app token
  fb = Koala::Facebook::API.new(user_access_token)
  fb.put_connections(user_id, {}) # TODO
rescue AuthenticationError
  begin
    # User access token has expired or is fake
    fb = Koala::Facebook::API.new(APP_FB_TOKEN)
    fb.put_connections(user_id, {}) # TODO
  rescue AuthenticationError
    # User hasn't authed the app on facebook
    puts "Could not authenticate"
    next
  end
rescue => e
  puts "Error when posting to facebook"
  puts e.message
  next
end
```